# Showing that Poynting’s theorem preserved with Proca Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, poynting-vector

The Proca Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4\mu_0}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2\mu_0\Lambda^2}A_{\mu}A^{\mu}+A_{\mu}J^{\mu}$$
Where $\Lambda=\frac{\hbar}{m_{\gamma}c^2}$.

The symmetric energy-momentum tensor that can be drived from Proca Lagrangian is: $$\theta^{\mu\nu}=\theta^{\mu\nu}_0+\frac{1}{\mu_0\Lambda^2}(A^{\mu}A^{\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}A_{\alpha}A^{\alpha})$$
Where $$\theta^{\mu\nu}_0=-\frac{1}{\mu_0}(g_{\alpha\lambda}F^{\mu\alpha}F^{\lambda\nu}+\frac{1}{4}g^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta})$$ is the symmetric energy-momentum tensor for $m_{\gamma} = 0$

How can i show that [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem) still preserved with $\theta^{\mu\nu}$ from Proca Lagrangian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let calculate $\partial_\nu\theta^{\mu\nu}$:
$$\begin{aligned} 
\partial_\nu\theta^{\mu\nu}& =\partial_\nu\theta^{\mu\nu}_0 + \frac{1}{\mu_0}(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2\partial_\nu(A^\mu A^\nu - \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \nu}A_\alpha A^\alpha) &{(1)}
\end{aligned}$$

Putting $\theta^{\mu\nu}_0$ into equation (1) we have

$$\begin{aligned}
\partial_\nu\theta^{\mu\nu} &=-\frac{1}{\mu_0}\partial_\nu(g_{\alpha\lambda}F^{\mu\alpha}F^{\lambda\nu}+ \frac{1}{4}g^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}) + \frac{1}{\mu_0}(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 \partial_\nu(A^\mu A^\nu - \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \nu}A_\alpha A^\alpha) &{(2)}
\\&= -\frac{1}{\mu_0}g_{\alpha\lambda} (\partial_\nu F^{\mu\alpha})F^{\lambda\nu} -\frac{1}{\mu_0}g_{\alpha\lambda}F^{\mu\alpha} (\partial_\nu F^{\lambda\nu}) - \frac{1}{4 \mu_0}\partial^\mu(F_{\alpha\beta}F^{\alpha\beta}) \\& +
\frac{1}{\mu_0}(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 (\partial_\nu A^\mu) A^\nu + 
\frac{1}{\mu_0}(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2  A^\mu (\partial_\nu A^\nu) - 
\frac{1}{2\mu_0}(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 g^{\mu \nu} \partial_\nu (A_\alpha A^\alpha) &{(3)}
\end{aligned}$$

For terms of equation (3) can be shown that

- The first term equals to $-\frac{1}{\mu_0}g_{\alpha\lambda}(g_{\beta\nu}\partial^\beta F^{\mu\alpha})F^{\lambda\nu}=-\frac{1}{\mu_0} F_{\alpha\beta}\partial^{\beta}F^{\mu\alpha}$
- The third term equals to $-\frac{1}{2\mu_0}F_{\alpha\beta}\partial^\mu F^{\alpha\beta}$
- The sum of first term and third term equals to zero, i.e.

$$\begin{aligned} -\frac{1}{2\mu_0} F_{\alpha\beta}\{2 \partial^{\beta}F^{\mu\alpha} +\partial^\mu F^{\alpha\beta}  \} &= 0 \ \ &{(4)} \end{aligned}$$

- The second term equals to $- F^{\mu\alpha} J_\alpha + \frac{1}{\mu_0}(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 F^{\mu\alpha} A_\alpha$                   because of Proca field equation, i.e. $$\begin{aligned} \partial_\nu F^{\lambda\nu} &= \mu_0 J^\lambda- (\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 A^\lambda \ \ &{(5)}
  \end{aligned}$$
- If we choose Lorentz condition, i.e. $\partial_\nu A^\nu=0$, the fifth term equals to zero;
- Sum of forth and sixth terms equal to
  $$\begin{aligned} -\frac{1}{\mu_0}(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 (-\partial_\nu A^\mu + \partial^\mu A_\nu)A^\nu = -\frac{1}{\mu_0}(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2  F^{\mu\nu} A_\nu \ &{ \ } \end{aligned}$$

Thus equation (3) becomes
$$\begin{aligned} \partial_\nu \theta^{\mu \nu} = - \frac{1}{\mu_0} F^{\mu\alpha}(\mu_0 J_\alpha) &= - F^{\mu\alpha}J_\alpha \equiv -f^{\mu} \ &{ \ (6)} \end{aligned}$$

Now easily  can be shown that
$$\begin{aligned}
\theta^{00} &=\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}(|E|^2 +(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 \phi^2) + \frac{1}{2 \mu_0}(|B|^2 +(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 A^2) \equiv W &{(7)}
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
\theta^{0i} &=\frac{1}{\mu_0}(\boldsymbol{E}×\boldsymbol{B} +(\frac{m_\gamma c}{\hbar})^2 \phi A) \equiv \boldsymbol{S} &{(8)}
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
f^\mu &= J_\alpha F^{\mu\alpha} = (\frac{(\boldsymbol{J} \cdot \boldsymbol{E})}{c} , \rho \boldsymbol{E} + \boldsymbol{J} × \boldsymbol{B}) = (f^0, f^i) &{(9)}
\end{aligned}$$

Where $W$ is energy density and $\boldsymbol{S}$ is Poyinting vector in Proca theorem.

Finally let calculate $\partial_\nu \theta^{\mu \nu}$ for $\mu=0$:

$$\begin{aligned}
\partial_\nu \theta^{0\nu} &= \partial_0 \theta^{00} + \partial_i \theta^{0i} = \frac{1}{c} (\frac{\partial W}{\partial t} + \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{S})
\\& = -f^0 = - \frac{\boldsymbol{J} \cdot \boldsymbol{E}}{c} \ &{(10)}
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore we show that Poynting's theorem preserved in proca theorem, i.e.
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial W}{\partial t} + \boldsymbol{\nabla} \cdot \boldsymbol{S}
&=  - \boldsymbol{J} \cdot \boldsymbol{E} \ &{(11)} \end{aligned}$$